# SSH works on localhost, but not on local network

Tags: ssh

Hello in recent days I have weird problem. I am getting ssh problem with -vvv:

```
debug2: resolving "ha-barebone.local" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ha-barebone.local [10.0.0.22] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.22 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ha-barebone.local port 22: Connection refused
```

but I can login on that computer as ssh user@127.0.0.1

It happens randomly. I tried to reinstall open ssh, then it worked, then it did not. Service restart does not help, looks like some problem with network. Ping resolves and works well.

Comment: same problem for me, same error output.